# DAW for Sound Design

Tags: post-production, film-sound-design

I'm new to the forum and am very excited to meet all of you!

I am s start up sound designer, who uses FL Studio as a DAW. As soon as finances permit, I will purchase Pro Tools as I am familiar with it and know it is an industry must if you are to be taken seriously. Also, Pro Tools is more suited to editing and mixing when it comes to sound for film, which is my main interest. The reason I chose FL is because I am into electronic music production as well and for the time being it does the job of a decent DAW.

The rest of my budget went into decent entry level mics, a Focusrite interface and a ZOOM H5 recorder. All entry level, but decent. I am in the process of putting together a proper show reel and find that my setup works fine for now. I am able to design sound for video.

Problem is, will people take me seriously if I tell them I work on FL? Honestly, that is something that really worries me. I am a firm believer that one's work should speak for itself, but people seem stuck on what you have. I get the logistical issues when one work on different DAW's and again, I will get Pro Tools as soon as I can.

I'm just wondering if there are any other people here in the same boat as I am, but who are really serious about breaking into the sound design business.

Is it something you try and overcome or do you make a plan to get Pro Tools?

Comment: Avid has a subscription based version of PT 12 that's quite affordable also you can easily test their software one month free of charge.

That said - it's still best to use and get to know the tools that you have and to focus on the end product - be it audio design or music production.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly? No-one will care what DAWyou use. All they will want is a good end product.

So as long as you can produce high quality audio you'all be fine.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input - glad to see that quality of work trumps all - which is my motto.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your creating great content, I don't see the necessity for better tools if they won't help much. Honing your craft is the most important. Of course, if you truly believe that your gear/tools are holding you back then I don't see the harm in upgrading.

Also, if your producing sound for film... the director most likely wants the best sounding audio so as long as you have that, then you're fine.

Also, I'm pretty sure FL Studio is regarded as quite a powerful DAW so I wouldn't really worry about it.